# Adding mesh to armature object that has the same bones

Tags: armature

---

I have two armature objects. the bone structure is the same on both (the 5 extra in arm_lower_r are the bones for the gun, everything else is the same). The weapon_and_bones object has animations that I want applied to the arms as well.

I have tried pasting the keyframes from the weapon_and_bones animation onto the arms, but it doesn't seem to work right. Is there an easy way that I can apply the arms mesh to the weapons_and_bones object since they use the same bone layout?

---

[image: Layers]
[image: Anim]